# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}[\omega + \omega^{-1}]$ is a PID for $\omega = e^{2\pi i /13}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

As the title suggests, I'm trying to prove that $\mathbb{Z}[\omega + \omega^{-1}]$ is a PID for $\omega = e^{2\pi i /13}$.  If we define $R := \mathbb{Z}[\omega + \omega^{-1}]$, then $\text{disc}(R) = 13^5$, so the Minkowski bound is $$ \frac{6!}{6^6}\sqrt{13^5} \approx 9.4.$$

We thus only need to see how $2,3,5$ and $7$ split.  We also know that $f_2 := f(P|2)$ is the order of $2$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/13\mathbb{Z})^\times$, so we get $f_2 = 6,~f_3 = 3,~f_5 = 2, f_7 = 6$, so $2$ and $7$ are inert, but $(3)$ and $(5)$ split into multiple primes.  We thus have \begin{align}
(3) &= \frak{p}_3\frak{p}_3'\\
(5) &= \frak{p}_5\frak{p}_5'\frak{p}_5''.
\end{align}

The question then becomes, how do we prove that these primes are principal?  I suppose it's the case that we could find the minimal polynomial of $\omega + \omega^{-1}$ via WolframAlpha, factor it $\mod 3$ and $\mod 5$ to find the ideals and prove they're principal one by one, but it feels like there has to be a more clever solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can work with the subfields: the factorization of $3$ comes from the quadratic subfield ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{13})$, that of $5$ from the cubic subfield. Computing cubic subfields of cyclotomic fields was already done by Gauss in the Disquisitiones.